# What is different between $G/N$ and $GN/N$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

What is different between $G/N$ and $GN/N$?

($G$ denotes a group, and N does a normal subgroup of G)

If you look at the element of each group above,

I think $G/N$ contains element of form $gN$, where $g$ is an element of G but not in $N$.

and $GN/N$ contains element of form $gnN$ which is equivalent to $gN$,

because $n$ is an element of $N$.

Then it looks like they indicate same group.

Is there anything wrong with my reasoning?

If so, could you point out and fix it?

Comment: $GN=G$ under your hypotheses.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. More generally, if $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ then $GH = G$, hence $GH/N = G/N$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thx:)

Answer (score 1):

The notation $GN/N$ may be useful in derived group.

For example:

$N$ is the normal subgroup of $G$, the $(G/N)^{\prime}=\phi(G)^{\prime}=\phi(G^{\prime})=G^{\prime}N/N=\{gH: g \in G^{\prime}\}$

$N$ may not be the normal subgroup of $G^{\prime}$, so the notation above is a right way to explain all the cosets.

By the way, $G^{\prime}N/N \cong G^{\prime}/(N \cap G^{\prime})$ is really useful.